# MVC- Manage Virtaul Path for Js and Css file

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, file

I want manage path for JS and Css file without changing filder structure 
 currrenlty my path is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/newTheme/css/font.css")" type="text/css" />
```

But i want path Like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Myproject/Content/newTheme/css/font.css")" type="text/css" />
```

Without changing folder structure
 One option is copy all files and folders in Myproject folder. But problem duplication of files.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have a folder name "animate.css" I can see written twice so it can be a issue. secondly if MyProject is name of your folder you don't need to write that in path.

Simply using ~ will take the root of the URL (the path you see in browser). The first one should work, just remove the duplicate animate.css from href attribute.